# Registration with text files only insert the || between words

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a registration with text file as I cannot use databases, but in my registration only the || between the words are inserted and the words do not show. Also, my file does not open automatically and I did set the directory to wrx. I have been working with this for quite a long time.

Comment: Try using `print_r($_POST)` to view the contents of the `$_POST` array and see what information you're getting from the webpage.

Comment: Why are you using this line of code : `if(!strstr($file, "$string"))` ?

Comment: If I went onto your website and I typed in http://yourwebsite.com/loginDetails.txt, I could read all the usernames and passwords that can access your site.

Comment: Can you see the username ||?

Comment: @learnerNo1 max_ meant security issue, anyone can see your user details...

Comment: Can you try writing dummy data to file? Like `$string = "username||password||fullname||emailaddress ";`

Comment: The print_r($_POST) did not work. It prints this to the screen print_r($_POST['username']); print_r($_POST['password']); I will try to add "" and see.

Comment: It takes long to test as everytime I need to shut down the server and start again to see the effects in the file.

Comment: It does not work, it adds  || to the dile instead of $username || $password || $name || $email

Comment: What about security, what can I do to make my file invisible, however first I need to make it work. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For one, this looks wrong:

```
$name = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['password'];
```

It should be:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Comment: This error it's fixed before. And with all of other suggestions only shows || $password instead of $username || $password || $name || $email

Comment: Fix it (and test it) and modify the code in the question so that people don't focus on that one.

Comment: Ok. I will modify it now. :-)